# Unable to create a new React Native Project (npx react-native init MyProject)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I am unable to create a new react native project. Below is the image : [image]

Instead of the whole template, I'm getting node-modules, package-lock.json and package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from the use of globally installed Yarn/NPM packages, which is generally not advised. To resolve this issue, you can clean up your environment using a combination of specific commands, depending on the ones you have installed in the past with the -g option:

- yarn global remove react-native
- yarn global remove react-native-cli
- npm uninstall -g react-native
- npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

To ensure that the global packages have been completely removed, check the following lists for any remaining react-native related items:

- yarn global list
- npm -g list

If you find anything related to react-native in these lists, remove them as well.